# C# - Pass a variable type to Generic method

Tags: c#, generics, npoi

I have this code using NPOI.
I'm trying to have an object that will be a either a`HSSFWorkbook` or a `XSSFWorkbook` depending on version of excel file.

It is possible to have an `Type` and past it to generic method in order to cast then return either `HSSFWorkbook` or `XSSFWorkbook`?

And also if it works, I will use `GetWorkBook()` in different method.

Please see my comment on constructor.

```
public class ExcelReader
{    
    public ExcelReader(filePath)
    {
        var isXls = Path.GetExtension(_filePath) == ".xls";
        // Is the following possible or is there any work around to get it work.
        var type = isXls ? HSSFWorkbook : XSSFWorkbook; 
        var workbook = GetWorkBook<type>();
        // Other init...
    }

    public T GetWorkBook<T>()
    {        
        return (T)Workbook.GetSheetAt();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Generics need to have the `Type` at compile time. So, in normal way you cannot pass the `Type` dynamically to a generic method.

You can use this though (using `reflection`)

```
public ExcelReader(filePath)
{
    var isXls = Path.GetExtension(_filePath) == ".xls";
    var type = isXls ? typeof(HSSFWorkbook) : typeof(XSSFWorkbook); //get the type for the method

    var getWorkBook = this.GetType().GetMethod("GetWorkBook"); //get the generic method dynamically
    var genericGetWorkBook = getWorkBook.MakeGenericMethod(type); //use the type

    var workBook = genericGetWorkBook.Invoke(this, null); //call the method
    //Other init...
}
```

In your case, a simpler alternative would be to *not use Generics*

```
public ExcelReader(filePath)
{
    var isXls = Path.GetExtension(_filePath) == ".xls";
    var workBook = GetWorkBook(); //then cast or return object directly
    //Other init...
}

public object GetWorkBook()
{        
    return Workbook.GetSheetAt();
}
```

to cast to desired type

```
HSSFWorkbook hSSFWorkbook = null;
XSSFWorkbook xSSFWorkbook = null;
if (isXls)
    hSSFWorkbook = (HSSFWorkbook)workBook;
else
    xSSFWorkbook = (XSSFWorkbook)workBook;
```

Comment: I guess I will use most of the time the interface on Workbook that inherits `HSSFWorkbook` and `XSSFWorkbook` provided by NPOI and if I need method specifically to `XSSFWorkbook` I will cast the interface to `XSSFWorkbook`. By the way, Thanks!

Comment: In that case your code will look very similar to the alternative approach. Just replace object with your interface.

Comment: It will need to cast in order to use the method of HSSF or XSSF.

Comment: In the last part of my answer I have shown the casting part as well.

Answer (score 0):

The ideal way is to have a base interface or class that both HSSFWorkbook and XSSFWorkbook inherit from. Then have

```
public IInterface GetWorkBook<T>()
{
     return Workbook.GetSheetAt();
}
```

and cast as required.

But if you don't have control on the classes you can  use dynamic

```
public dynamic GetWorkBook<T>()
{
     return Workbook.GetSheetAt();
}
```

But do read up on dynamic before you go that route.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply change your implementation like this

```
    public ExcelReader(filePath)
{
    var isXls = Path.GetExtension(_filePath) == ".xls";

    if(typeof(isXls) == typeof(HSSFWorkbook))
          var workbook= GetWorkBook<HSSFWorkbook>();
    else if(typeof(isXls) == typeof(XSSFWorkbook))
          var workbook= GetWorkBook<XSSFWorkbook >();
    else{}
}

public T GetWorkBook<T>()
{  
    if(typeof(T) == typeof(HSSFWorkbook)     
     return (T)(object)(HSSFWorkbook)Workbook.GetSheetAt();
    return (T)(object)(XSSFWorkbook)Workbook.GetSheetAt();
}
```

Just use conditional statements based on your types.